# Wrapping React Component Generically

Tags: reactjs, react-props, react-modal

I've posted this on Reactiflux but may get more traction here. I've created a sandbox to demonstrate my need: https://codesandbox.io/s/xvnk0znw7z

What I'm trying to do is create  a generic modal wrapper that I can use to encapsulate several components; in the sandbox, the component is a date range picker, but I also have a `formik` component for example.

The thing is, the Apply and Clear buttons need to be a part of the wrapping modal, and not the child component it wraps.

However, when clicking on Apply or Clear, saving the child component state to the Context (not included for brevity) is really the responsibility of the child component itself; only it knows how it should do it.

In the example above, that would be the `ok` and `clear` methods of `DatesPicker`. Intuitively, I would call `children.ok` and `children.clear` from the wrapping modal, but I know for a fact that's not how it should be done.

I looked a lot at the Cat and Mouse render-prop example in React's docs, but I can't get my head around how I can apply this here.

Comment: What is that you are looking for?

Comment: @RohithMurali I'm sorry but is my question not clear?

Comment: It would be easier to understand if you can make your needs a little more clear.